# Generating different shades of the same colour in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, color-palette

I want to generate different shades of a colour going from lighter tone to darker tone

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "red"))
colfunc(10)

plot(rep(1,10),col=colfunc(10),pch=19,cex=3)
```

[image]

If I try to run this for a single colour

```
 colfunc <- colorRampPalette("green")
 colfunc(10)
 [1] "#00FF00" "#00FF00" "#00FF00" "#00FF00" "#00FF00" "#00FF00"
 [7] "#00FF00" "#00FF00" "#00FF00" "#00FF00"
```

It returns me the same values. How can I generate different shades of a single colour say going from light green to darker green?

Comment: Pick more than one green? Heeps of colors in `grDevice::colors`. See [this cheat sheet](http://bc.bojanorama.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/rcolorsheet.pdf). Package `RColorBrewer` have the `Greens` palette.

Comment: You can also play with `rgb`: adapted from the Examples: `rgb(green = (0:10)/10, red = 0, blue = 0)`

Comment: Another [chart of R colors](http://research.stowers.org/mcm/efg/R/Color/Chart/) which may be useful in this context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fc <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "darkgreen"))
plot(rep(1, 10),col = fc(10), pch = 19, cex = 3)
```

Is it what you need?

[image: clrs]